# How to localise html5 meta tag information

Tags: html, localization, internationalization, meta-tags

I am building a website designed for 4 different languages, using `Sinatra`, and using the `I18n` libs to insert localised content, but I am wondering what to do about the standard `HTML5` meta tags for things like `description` and `keywords`, and how Google and other search engines will treat them if I localise the content in those tags.

Ideally I want to be able to tell Google (et al), perhaps via information in a `sitemap.xml` file or something (though I'm not certain that's even possible), that the site may be parsed in these 4 languages, and so present correctly localised keywords, and descriptions to users depending on their locale preference.

Likewise I want to be able to localise the information going out to Twitter and Facebook by localising the relevant `og` meta tags, and twitter:card` meta tags.

**Note:** the actual page URLs will be the same no matter the language chosen, localised content is rendered in the `Slim` templates themselves.

Is it enough, for example, to specify

```
html lang='de_DE'
```

I'm after a best-practice and DRY way of achieving nicely localised search result summary information for my international users.

Comment: How can the pages have the same URL? Are you using language negotiation, or do you localize the content client-side?

Comment: The content is stored in `I18n` files and injected by the `Slim` templates on request, based on, in cascading order, the default (English), the browser default, or what's in the user's session.

Answer (score 7):

If the different language versions reside at the same URL, then what search engines get is what your server sends to a browser that does specify any language preferences. According to your description, it thus seems that they always get the default (English) version. No `meta` tags or `lang` attributes can affect this. (And search engines ignore `lang` attributes.)

So you should arrange thing so that each language version of a page has a URL of its own. (The difference could be in the query part only, e.g. `?lang=de-DE` at the end.) Moreover, the versions should be interlinked, with `link` elements or with visible `a` links, so that when a search engine has found one version, it will find the other versions, too, just by following links.

P.S. Writing `<meta name=keywords ...>` tags is probably waste of time. Google has [ignored](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.fi/2009/09/google-does-not-use-keywords-meta-tag.html) them long ago.

Answer (score 6):

You can provide `meta` elements with content in different languages on the same HTML document by using the [`lang` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-lang-and-xml:lang-attributes):

```
<meta name="description" lang="de" content="…" />
<meta name="description" lang="en" content="…" />
<meta name="description" lang="es" content="…" />
<meta name="description" lang="fr" content="…" />
```

If any third party services like Google or Facebook recognize this is a different question which cannot be answered in general, depends on the specific service, context and the point in time, as things might change rapidly.

However (as [Jukka K. Korpela notes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17897628/1591669), too), in general you should use separate URLs for translations. Give users (and search enginges etc.) the ability to link to a specific language version.